# Como imprimir valor de variável JavaScript em tag HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, input, data

Eu gostaria de limitar a seleção do input date dessa maneira, porém não está funcionando.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = new Date();
  var dia     = data.getDate();          
  var mes     = data.getMonth();         
  var ano4    = data.getFullYear();
  var str_data = ano4 + '-' + (mes+1) + '-' + dia;
  <?php $data=str_data;?>
</script>
<input type="date" name="data" max="<?=$data?>"/>
```

Comment: Não entendi,  explique para nós o que você quer exibir e limitar exatamente?

Comment: Você quer pegar a variável JavaScript `str_data` e jogar dentro do PHP? Isso não é possível.

Comment: Isso mesmo Lucas Costa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja mais fácil trabalhar preenchendo a data máxima direto no `PHP`:

```
<input type="date" name="data" max="<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>" />
```

Mas se você quiser limitar pelo `JavaScript` lembre-se que o `HTML5` permite que os usuários alterem o valor no `Input` com o teclado e pelas setas, então você tem de remover essas entradas para assegurar que a data máxima do seu `Input` seja respeitada (claro que isso não dispensa a necessidade de validar no servidor também).

```js
var dateInput = document.getElementById("data");
var d         = new Date();
var dia       = d.getDate();          
var mes       = d.getMonth();         
var ano       = d.getFullYear();
var data      = ano + '-' + (mes+1) + '-' + dia;
dateInput.setAttribute("max", data);
```

```css
.no-spin::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="data" id="data" class="no-spin" onkeydown="return false"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var data = new Date();
var dia     = data.getDate();          
var mes     = data.getMonth();         
var ano4    = data.getFullYear();
var str_data = ano4 + '-' + (mes+1) + '-' + dia;
inp = document.getElementsByName('data')[0];
inp.setAttribute("max", str_data);
```

```html
<input type="date" name="data"/>
```

Ou, em vez de `inp.setAttribute("max", str_data);`:

```
...
inp.max = str_data;
```

Comment: dessa forma você trava a escolha no calendário mas ainda é possível editar pelo input

Comment: O estranho é que o executável aqui do stackoverflow funciona, mas no meu código não

Comment: era só colocar o script debaixo do input kkkkkkk
deu certo aqui obrigado!

Comment: hehe. De nada @EmanuelDeOliveiraPeres

Comment: @CaiqueRomero se está do lado cliente é possível tudo, até podes mudar o type do input e escrever o que quiseres... As verificações finais e cruciais/definitivas têm de ser feitas depois do lado servidor

Comment: De fato é indispensável a validação no lado do servidor, mas na minha opinião se for pra limitar parcialmente no lado do cliente então é mais fácil nem limitar.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Para mim verificações do lado cliente são mais para ser 'user friendly' do que outra coisa. Muitas vezes é escusado/chato fazer uma requisição ao servidor cada tentativa/submição, podendo logo indicar-se o input esperado

Comment: Sim, não deixa de ser um "floreio".

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Mas já impede (ou mostra o que não pode ser/fazer) antes de tentar, é menos chato no caso de falha para o utilizador final

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue pegar uma variável gerada pelo JavaScript e atribuir seu valor dentro de um script PHP desta forma.

Em vez disso, atribua à tag `input` o valor do JavaScript usando `setAttribute()`:

```
var data = new Date();
var dia     = data.getDate();          
var mes     = data.getMonth();         
var ano4    = data.getFullYear();
var str_data = ano4 + '-' + (mes+1) + '-' + dia;
el = document.getElementsByName("data")[0];
el.setAttribute("max", str_data); // ou, de forma mais curta: el.max = str_data;
```

Comment: Cara pior que não está funcionando o javascript, porque quando eu coloco a data manualmente no max funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: Na verdade consegue, só não é aconselhavel.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Ok, mas não da forma que ele colocou na pergunta. Até adicionei esse detalhe à resposta. Valeu!

Comment: ao invés do "document.getElementByName()" , atribua um "id" para o input... por exemplo o id="data", ai vc chama dele por "document.getElementById('data');" 
Vai ver o problema é que o "name" exista em mais de um atributo, ai não funciona mesmo

Comment: @RafaelAugusto O index [0] pega o primeiro elemento pelo nome. Se tiver mais de um, não tem problema.